# How to check if the route is active?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want different color on my nav when its in my homepage. How to check if the homepage route is active, than i want to give different styles on my navbar ? (if else statement). I've tried to use window.location.href. It works, but i have to refresh my page first.

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("/") > -1) {
   $('nav').addClass('nav-scroll');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<Navbar default collapseOnSelect fixedTop>
    <Nav pullRight>
     <Navbar.Brand>
      <Link to="/">WakafKita</Link>
     </Navbar.Brand>
     <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Nav>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
     <Nav pullLeft>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} href="/" to="/">
       Beranda
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} to="/menu">
       Menu
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} to="/menu">
       Menu
      </NavItem>
      <NavDropdown eventKey={4} title="Akun" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
       <MenuItem eventKey={4.1} componentClass={Link} href="/masuk" to="/masuk">Masuk</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem eventKey={4.1} componentClass={Link} href="/daftar" to="/daftar">Daftar</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
     </Nav>
     <Navbar.Form className="navInput">
      <form>
       <FormGroup>
        <InputGroup>
         <InputGroup.Addon className="nbg">
          <Glyphicon glyph="search" />
         </InputGroup.Addon>
         <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Cari Judul, Nama, atau Campaign" />
        </InputGroup>
       </FormGroup>
      </form>
     </Navbar.Form>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
   </Navbar>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Comment: It would be better if you can add some code here. So that we can know what have you done so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react router version4,  then you must be getting history as props and you can check the active route with the help of:

```
 history.pathname
```

Or else you can go javascript way

```
 window.location
```

Comment: i'll try it. Thanks! @Captain Jack Sparrow

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using react-router4 you should able to use `Link` component for navigation also this component includes props like `activeClassName` and `activeStyle` that help you to modify active mode.
for more information visit :
[Active links tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links)